# Vue.js & Firebase Auth | TwitterAuthProvider is not a function/constructor

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Despite scouring SO/internet I just can't solve this problem.

I'm trying to hook up Firebase Twitter Authentication in my Vue.js app ([Webpack Starter Template](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/)) and following the official Firebase docs.

This is the error I'm receiving upon attempting Twitter authentication:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider is not a constructor
at VueComponent.twitterauth (App.vue?26cd:49)
at boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:190)
at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:2004)
at HTMLAnchorElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1802)
```

I'm initializing Firebase as an instance property in `/src/main.js`:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import config from './firebaseconfig'
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

And my function for Twitter authentication is in the base `/src/App.vue`:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    twitterauth() {
      var provider = new this.$firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
      return this.$firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
        alert('success')
      }, (error) => {
        alert('fail')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The strange thing is that I'm able to get firestore data in a component, `/src/components/Main.vue`:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
     <h1 class="is-size-3">Newest Setups</h1>
     <p v-for="tool in usertools">
       <em>{{ tool.type }}</em><br />
       <b>{{ tool.tool }}</b><br />
       <em>{{ tool.note }}</em>
     </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Main',
  data () {
    return {
      usertools: [],
      loading: true
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$firebase.firestore().collection('user-tools').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      this.loading = false
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let data = {
          'type': doc.data().type,
          'tool': doc.data().tool,
          'note': doc.data().note
        }
        this.usertools.push(data)
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Which docs are you following? The [ones I'm checking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login) use the `firebase` "module", instead of a firebase initialized app, which probably doesn't have the `auth` property.

Comment: yeah, that is the doc I'm following. am i referencing the wrong thing or importing the module improperly?

Comment: Try with `var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider()` and `return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` That way you will use the `firebase` object, instead of your initialized app (`$firebase`). The docs refer with `firebase` to the module per se.

Comment: This worked! - As long as I re-`import * as firebase from 'firebase'` in the component file. However I was hoping to avoid having to re-include firebase in every Vue template, hence why I tried to do it via the Vue.prototype. Is that not advisable?

Comment: @yuriy636 Thank you so much. I was doing the same thing and you saved the day. Actually, you saved the night because it took me all day. but thanks to you it won't be an issue tomorrow. :)